# How do I install and use a JSON editor in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, json, eclipse-plugin

I wish to install a JSON editor in Eclipse, and I am trying to use [Eclipse JSON Editor Plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/) which is mentioned in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943720/1743811) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357521/is-there-a-decent-json-editor-around).

I have copied the zip file from Sourceforge. How do I install the plugin and then how do I configure the editor in Eclipse to recognise and edit JSON files? I do not know how to install plugins manually so please assume ignorance and give detailed descriptions.

If there are better/newer solutions please indicate them.

Comment: You could also use the Eclipse Javascript editor (see the answer by noirbizarre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357521/is-there-a-decent-json-editor-around). The plugin you mentioned seems to have some bugs, see comments at eclipse marketplace: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-editor-plugin#.UU_WPeUR_H1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just went to the site and downloaded the file. You want the zip file that is downloaded. Once you have that, go to Help -> Install New Software. Click the Add.. Button and then the Archive button, and specify the location of the zip file you downloaded, and then proceed through the installation.

Make sure you DESELECT group items by Category (see answer below)

The zip file provided is set up for this type of installation within Eclipse.

Comment: There was no "dropins" folder directly under C:\program Files\eclipse. I created one, copied the Zip file and restarted but this doesn't seem to show any change either (Do I have to remove the old *.jar files I copied?)

Comment: Thanks for continuing. I am still struggling. When I select "Archive" it gives me "Scheme not supported"

Comment: You don't put anything in the dialog and just push the "Archive" button? It should pop up a dialog allowing you to select a local file. This is not happening? If that's the case you might have a messed up Eclipse installation (I'm also suspicious because you don't have a "dropins" folder which comes with the installation).

Comment: I get a list of error messages such as 
Error
Sun Dec 18 20:23:01 GMT 2011
No repository found at file:/C:/Users/pm286/Downloads/JsonEditorPlugin-0.9.4.zip. or eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736

It seems to be much harder for me to install this than I thought. I have always found plugins impenetrable and this struggle is typical! Sorry for the trouble - I doubt you can solve it remotely

Comment: Thanks @Francis - I will reinstall Eclipse and revisit. +1 for your trouble

Comment: It's pretty easy. Basically the zip file is the whole "update site" packaged up. So if you point the installer at that, it should just install easily. There is no need to copy anything anywhere. When you install you either point Eclipse to a remote update site URL (which is effectively a directory) or can point it to an archive, which is what you have. Good luck!

Comment: accepted this as it appears to be the most likely to work even though I can't

Comment: Refer to answer by fiacobelli - Deselect Group Items by Category is missing from these instructions.

Comment: This answer is correct. But if you have tried to install a plugin for this and it doesn't seem to work, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 29):

So I got it to work on Galileo and it apparently can work in newer Eclipse versions.
Just download the zip file, go to:

1. Help->Install New Software
2. Add-> Archive and select the zip file.
3. **DESELECT "Group Items By category"** option at the bottom.
4. install.

There are more details here (search for comment by 'stokiematt' towards the bottom). http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/forums/forum/957258/topic/3311846

Comment: thanks. fwiw search for 'stokiematt' on the page you reference to find the comment from the original author of the plugin.

Comment: I followed these steps! exact same steps. but a dialog box is popped out saying *'Installing Software' has encountered a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed!*

Answer (score 8):

You need to copy the file `json.editor.plugin_0.9.4.jar` inside plugins folder of the zip archive inside the plugins folder of your eclipse installation.

After that relaunch eclipse, and the plugin will be installed .

To open a file with the json editor you have to select the file in package explorer then right click on it and select Open With and then Json editor :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have already done that (and the *.jar under features) but it didn't seem to do anything so thought I was doing it wrong. I am unclear how to (a) verify it has been installed and (b) make it work on JSON files.

Comment: To check if the plugin is installed you can go to Preferences and you should find Json Editor . To open a file with it you should select it in package explorer and then select open with ---> JSON Editor .

Comment: There is no "Json Editor" directly under Preferences (or any of the descendants that I have explored). I am on Windows 7 and using Build id: 20110615-0604. Also there is no trace of it under Help-> About Eclipse -> Installation Deatils -> Plugins

Comment: I've just tried now on my installation on OS X Lion (Eclipse 3.7.1 - M20110909-1335), i've placed the json.editor.plugin_0.9.4.jar under plugins folder and json.editor.plugin.feature_0.9.4.jar under feature folder of my eclipse installation. No problem and everythings work fine ... I can't try now on Windows 7, but i can try tomorrow at my office PC.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am continuing to browse around my installation. Note @Francis_Upton answer which suggests that your solution no longer works.

Comment: However tomorrow i will try also on Windows and i let you know .

Comment: @aleroot, I think what you are doing could also work, though I think it's not supposed to (you are supposed to use dropins to do that manually). But installing directly from the zip file (and not the enclosed jar files) should be much easier.

Comment: I tried what aleroot suggested for OS X lion and didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use eclipse inbuilt JavaScript Editor!

```
Window > Preferences
General > Editors > File Associations
Add... > File type: *.json
Select *.json file type > Add... (Associated editors) > JavaScript Editor
Make it default
```

This works great for me. Give it a try!

Comment: Except the missing outline. On the other hand, the plug-In is unsigned and loaded tons of dependencies. +1

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works. However, I had a problem getting the new plugin for JSON editing to take effect. For my installation, an Eclipse-centric JSON editor was being used and took precedence over any other JSON plugin. Nothing I could do had any effect on the JSON editing. Specifically, JSON comments were being marked as errors. So I had to do a deep dive into Eclipse configuration.

I use an all Mac ecosystem, so this description is based on that.

What I found was that the "About" Eclipse popup has an interesting feature.
On the bottom of the "about" screen is a button labeled "Installation Details". Clicking on that brings up a screen that lists all the "modules" and "plugins" being used in this installation.

There is a "filter" field so I put "json" into that and got a list of all JSON features. Clicking on them, a button labeled "Uninstall..." on the bottom of the screen would get enabled. After uninstalling any Eclipse-centric JSON feature, my JSON files were being displayed all gray and no errors.

At this point I reinstalled the first JSON plugin I encountered and BANG! all my JSON was colored, comments were not errors. Quick syntax color config changes and I'm working in JSON with comments and not getting errors.

If you have tried to apply a JSON plugin (or perhaps other plugins) without success, perhaps this will be of help.